# This use of std::make_pair works fine in GCC 3 and 4. It fails in Visual Studio C++ 2010. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stl, compiler-errors

This compiles fine in GCC 3 and 4.  MSVC++ can't figure out the type of noFunction and throws some hideous errors.   Note if you cast noFunction to BFunction, it works just fine in VS2010.

**My question: is this a defect in VS2010, or GCC bending the rules?**

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef bool (*AFunction)(int arg1, int arg2);
typedef bool (*BFunction)(long arg1, bool arg2);

bool noFunction(long, bool) { return true; }

void test(AFunction a)
{

    make_pair(a, noFunction); //fails in VS2010

}
```

**N.B. casting noFunction to BFunction fixes the problem in VS2010.**

```
make_pair(a, (BFunction)noFunction);  //works everywhere
```

.

.

.

Here is the error for reference:

```
    1>  makepairtest.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\type_traits(197): error C2752: 'std::tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>' : more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtr1common(356): could be 'std::tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty&&>'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtr1common(350): or       'std::tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty&>'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\type_traits(962) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::remove_reference<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(26) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::decay<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>          c:\xxx\makepairtest.cpp(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Unrefwrap<_Type>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Type=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\type_traits(965): error C2528: 'abstract declarator' : pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\type_traits(349): error C2528: 'type' : pointer to reference is illegal
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\type_traits(967) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::add_pointer<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(148): error C2535: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base(const _Ty1 &,const _Ty2)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=bool (__cdecl *)(int,int),
1>              _Ty2=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(134) : see declaration of 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=bool (__cdecl *)(int,int),
1>              _Ty2=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(174) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=bool (__cdecl *)(int,int),
1>              _Ty2=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
1>          c:\xxx\makepairtest.cpp(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=bool (__cdecl *)(int,int),
1>              _Ty2=bool (__cdecl &)(long,bool)
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the address of `noFunction` works with VC10 and gcc 4.5.2, i.e.:

```
make_pair(a, &noFunction);
```

Per the error message you posted, I would guess it has to do with how VC handles binding to rvalues.

Comment: what would be the advantage of taking the address over just casting it to the intended type?

Comment: Using the C-style cast you're using right now, one could argue the `typedef` could change and the types might go out of sync without your compiler helping you catch it. If you were using `static_cast`, the only advantage I can think of is less typing ;) (of taking the address vs `static_caat`ing)

Comment: The advantage of using the 'address-of' operator over using a cast is that the cast will allow you to accidentally pass a pointer to an incorrect function type.

Answer (score 1):

"My question: is this a defect in VS2010, or GCC bending the rules?"

When in doubt blame Visual C++ and/or Bill Gates. Note that there is a difference between the value of noFunction when used in your code and the type defined by BFunction. noFunction will be a **reference** to a function whereas BFunction defines a **pointer** to a function. It is a bit hard to explain but it might help to contemplate the following program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>


bool noFunction(long, bool) { return true; }

typedef bool (function_ref)(long, bool);
typedef bool (*function_ptr)(long, bool);

int
main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(noFunction).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(&noFunction).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(function_ref).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(function_ptr).name() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that Visual C++ is choking on function references. I'm not sure if there is a legitimate reason why it would reject that but I would expect that you should be able to construct a pair with types that are a model of copy constructable. Eg you should be able construct but not assign `std::pair<int, int const&>`.